# Make this implementation of counting sort Pythonic

Tags: python, sorting

This is my crude attempt at implementing a counting sort algorithm. My goal is to be able to sort lists of ints, negative and positive. As you can see I've employed such hacks as `return res[1:]` to get by. I'd appreciate any feedback I can get to make this a more pythonic implementation.

```
def find_min(a_list):
    min = a_list[0]
    for item in a_list:
        if item < min:
            min = item
    return min


def find_max(a_list):
    max = a_list[0]
    for item in a_list:
        if item > max:
            max = item
    return max


def counting_sort(a_list):
    min = find_min(a_list)
    max = find_max(a_list)

    counts = [0] * (abs(max) + abs(min) + 1)

    for i in range(0, len(a_list), 1):
        counts[a_list[i] - min] += 1

    sum = 0
    for j in range(0, len(counts), 1):
        sum += counts[j]
        counts[j] = sum

    res = [0] * (len(a_list)+1)
    for k in range(0, len(a_list), 1):
        res_index = counts[a_list[k]-min]
        res[res_index] = a_list[k]
        counts[a_list[k]-min] -= 1

    return res[1:]
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.11

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### My two cents:

You can get rid of `def find_min(a_list):` and `def find_max(a_list):`. Instead, use python's built-ins `min()` and `max()`:

> #### `min(iterable[, key])`
>
> Return the smallest item in an iterable
>   or the smallest of two or more arguments.
>
> If one positional argument is provided, iterable must be a non-empty
>   iterable (such as a non-empty string, tuple or list). The smallest
>   item in the iterable is returned. If two or more positional arguments
>   are provided, the smallest of the positional arguments is returned.

> #### `max(iterable[, key])`
>
> Return the largest item in an iterable or the
>   largest of two or more arguments.
>
> If one positional argument is provided, iterable must be a non-empty
>   iterable (such as a non-empty string, tuple or list). The largest item
>   in the iterable is returned. If two or more positional arguments are
>   provided, the largest of the positional arguments is returned.

So you'll have:

```
...
min_element, max_element = min(a_list), max(a_list)
...
```

Now, regarding you algorithm, you can avoid those *hacks* you were talking about by rewriting your function as:

```
def count_sort(array):
    min_element, max_element = min(array), max(array)
    count_array = [0] * (max_element - min_element + 1)

    for val in array:
        count_array[val - min_element] += 1

    sorted_array = []
    for i in range(min_element, max_element + 1):
        if count_array[i - min_element] > 0:
            for j in range(0, count_array[i - min_element]):
                sorted_array.append(i)

    return sorted_array
```

More, as [@ChatterOne](/q/149069/#comment280328_149071) mentioned, instead of the final `for` loop with append, you could do:

```
sorted_array.extend([i] * count_array[i - min_element])
```

#### So, your final code would look like this:

```
def count_sort(array):
    min_element, max_element = min(array), max(array)
    count_array = [0] * (max_element - min_element + 1)

    for val in array:
        count_array[val - min_element] += 1

    sorted_array = []
    for i in range(min_element, max_element + 1):
        if count_array[i - min_element] > 0:
            for j in range(0, count_array[i - min_element]):
                sorted_array.append(i)

    return sorted_array


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_array = [3, 2, -1, 1, 5, 0, 10, 18, 25, 25]
    print(count_sort(my_array))
```

or

```
def count_sort(array):
    min_element, max_element = min(array), max(array)
    count_array = [0] * (max_element - min_element + 1)

    for val in array:
        count_array[val - min_element] += 1

    sorted_array = []
    for i in range(min_element, max_element + 1):
        if count_array[i - min_element] > 0:
            sorted_array.extend([i] * count_array[i - min_element])

    return sorted_array


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_array = [3, 2, -1, 1, 5, 0, 10, 18, 25, 25]
    print(count_sort(my_array))
```

#### Extras:

You can see that I also added `if __name__ == '__main__'`. By doing the `main` check, you can have that code execute only when you want to run the module as a program, and not have it execute when someone just wants to import your module and call your functions themselves.

---

I also changed the names `min` and `max`(*which are already built-ins in Python*) to `min_element` and `max_element`, respectively.

---

#### And the result:

> ```
> [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 18, 25, 25]
> ```

Comment: There's not much of a difference, but it's probably worth mentioning that instead of the final `for` loop with `append`, you could do `sorted_array.extend([i] * count_array[i - min_element])`

Comment: @ChatterOne good idea! I'll add this as a side-note in my answer ^^

Comment: Gents, thank you do much for the feedback. I should have mentioned that I purposely did not use the built in `min` and `max` functions in spirit of writing as much of it on my own as possible.